# Transcode to webm utilizing multiple threads / processors

Tags: ffmpeg, webm

I'm trying to utilize my multiple processors for my webm conversion but no matter what I do the process is single-threaded and takes forever. Is this possible? Any sample conversion strings?

```
-threads 8
```

Just gets ignored. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You probably using version of ffmpeg-php compiled with ffmpeg less than 0.7 version (which is first version to support multithreading).

BTW, I'm not sure but probably even if you'll use more recent version of ffmpeg to build ffmpeg-php extension the php itself should be built as multithreaded (which isn't default and not provided by packages in most Linux distributions)

Comment: I'm having the same issue using a git checkout from Friday. I think it's unsupported.